# Read List from SharePoint using PHP

Tags: sharepoint-server, php

I'm struck with PHP SharePoint integration. Is there any simple PHP method to read list from SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013 or 2016?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17545824/1294606

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I used stackoverflow.com/q/17545824/1294606 But No luck. Then I used nuSoap Library. Then Authentication is happening but not able to fetch list.Giving List Doesn't exists Error.

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/OfficeDev/PHP-App-for-SharePoint?

Comment: Also check this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2012/SPC030

Comment: I have not created App in Share point.A simple List.I can access it through URL.I want to access through my  PHP code.

Comment: Vadim has some, https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/31/sharepoint-online-client-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this api: https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API

I have tried and it works perfectly. you can also find how to's of the api on same link.

```
<?php
include "Thybag\SharePointAPI.php";
include "Thybag\Auth\SharePointOnlineAuth.php";
include "Thybag\Auth\SoapClientAuth.php";
include "Thybag\Auth\StreamWrapperHttpAuth.php";
include "Thybag\Service\ListService.php";
include "Thybag\Service\QueryObjectService.php";
use Thybag\SharePointAPI;
$sp = new SharePointAPI('<user@domain.onmicrosoft.com>','<password>','<path_to_WSDL>,'SPONLINE'); //SPONLINE if your point is online else add true instead
$data = $sp->read('Documents');
var_dump($data);
```

This will return you the array of all lists stored on sharepoint. Then based on your need you can get the file name by calling array from the above array list.